# How to Load amount using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?

Tags: mysql, database

i'm unable to load amount using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
I have a text file where there is one column called 'Amount'. My problem is this field has values as 20,200.00 and -61,066.11 etc in the text file. When I try to load these values in my MySQL database, it loads only 20 and -61.
What should I do to load the full amount in my table?
I am using Decimal(10,2) data type.
I am using following query.
**LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Dataction123/Desktop/nordic.txt' INTO TABLE spend_nordic LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';**

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Dataction123/Desktop/nordic.txt' IGNORE
INTO TABLE spend_nordic 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(int_col, @float_col)
SET float_col = replace(@float_col, ',', '.');
```

**Explanation :**

MySQL casts the value into the column type when it reads it from the file, *before* applying the transformations described in the SET clause. If you instruct it to read it into a variable the value is handled as string from the beginning. float_col is name of field.

For reference [Click here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Thanks Himesh for your comment. In above query what is int_col and @float_col? Sorry I am new to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this query now.

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Dataction123/Desktop/nordic.txt' IGNORE
INTO TABLE spend_nordic 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(InvoiceNum, @Amount)
SET Amount = replace(@Amount, ',', '.'); When I use above query I get error 1054 - Unknown column 'InvoiceNum'. Here InvoiceNum is the field which is there in my file and 'Amount' is DB culumn,

Comment: Try this LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Dataction123/Desktop/nordic.txt' IGNORE
INTO TABLE spend_nordic 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(int_col, @Amount)
SET float_col = replace(@Amount, ',', '.');

Comment: Actually you need to go through mysql documentation and example given https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

Comment: Going through the link. Thank you. Can I load this field as an varchar and later remove semicolon and convert the field to Decimal?